# Javascript Slideshow Slowing My Site

Tags: javascript, image, slideshow

NOTE:I just noticed that when I hover over a menu item, it doesn't register until the image is loaded. Not sure why this is

I just added an image slideshow to the index page of my site. I finally got it working and uploaded it. Now the slideshow will go through the 5 images, but the load time is pretty significant, and there is a major delay when I try to click on any of the menus.

Here is the code at the beginning of the file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var image1=new Image()
image1.src="image1.JPG"
var image2=new Image()
image2.src="image2.JPG"
var image3=new Image()
image3.src="image3.JPG"
var image4=new Image()
image4.src="image4.JPG"
var image5=new Image()
image5.src="image5.JPG"
//-->
    </script>
```

And the code in the body of the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            <!--
            //variable that will increment through the images
            var step=1
            function slideit(){
            //if browser does not support the image object, exit.
            if (!document.images)
               return
            document.slide.src="images/image"+step+".JPG"
            if (step<5)
               step++
            else
            step=1
            //call function "slideit()" every 2.5 seconds
            setTimeout("slideit()",2500)
            }
            slideit()
            //-->
            </script>
```

Any idea why the page is so slow now?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The timer is 2500ms, or 2.5 seconds. Is this what to mean?

Comment: P.S., we haven;t needed to hide JavaScript blocks using "<!--" since 1996.

Comment: Maybe decreasing the size of images can help.

Comment: Sigh, that was it, the images were HUGE and it was taking forever to load/resize. Boy do I feel dumb!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be a number of reasons.

Does the slideshow wait for all the images to load before it starts? If that's the case, consider putting the slideshow script at the bottom of the html page, if possible. That way, all the other content loads first.

Is the slideshow animated? Do images slowly move across the screen every 2500 seconds? If this is the case, the code you're using may have too small of a value for its setTimeout() function. Consider raising it, or risking it and using CSS3 transitions for animating.